# Proving that a random variable is not absolutely continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Anyone who knows the measure theoretic framework for random variables will know that there exists random variables that are neither discrete (i.e. taking countably many values) or absolutely continuous (i.e. having a probability density function). However, **how does one go about proving that a random variable is not absolutely continuous?**

Proving the negative that "this random variable does not have a probability density function" strikes me as a rather difficult task. I can imagine that there's some sort of proof by contradiction that can be done here, but I fail to see what contradiction can be drawn. After all, the definition of a probability density function is not very restrictive. Is there some equivalent property that I've missed?

Comment: The density function can be seen as essentially being the derivative of the cumulative distribution function.  So integrate the derivative of the cdf across the support where the derivative exists, and if that integral is not $1$ then the distribution is not absolutely continuous. If the integral plus the sum of the positive probabilities (jump discontinuities) is not $1$ then the distribution is singular